# Problems with users in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I found many problem to authenticate into a db when `"auth=true"` in mongodb.conf.

I create my database, I selected it and the I add the user like this:

```
db.addUser( { user: "USER",
              pwd: "PWD",
              roles: [ "userAdminAnyDatabase ]
            } )
```

(I tried with all roles)

But when I try to login by MongoHub I get `"errmsg unauthorized"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a 2.4.X version of MongoDB according to the way you are adding a user (using roles).

Can you test authenticating with the mongoshell and the db.auth() command, as this may be an issue with Mongohub (which was last updated 2 years ago according to github)